# Ricoh MP C2011 printer works using cups on armhf ubuntu, and then stuck "sending data to printer"

Tags: ubuntu, cups, ppd

Printer: Ricoh MP C2011 (or MP C2011SP?)

http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Ricoh/Ricoh-MP_C2011

View PPD file: http://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=PDF-Ricoh&printer=Ricoh-MP_C2011&show=1

Printer Added via CUPS web interface.

Print Command: $ lp -d c2011 test.pdf

CUPS version: 2.1.3

CUPS installed via command: $ sudo apt install cups

System: Ubuntu xenial armhf via "LinuxDeploy" app on Android.

The system also has foo2zjs installed, works well with HP LaserJet P1102w.

===========================================================================

The printer works fine when the CUPS Status says "Idle".

After a pdf file normally printed, the status turn to Idle - "Sending data to printer." And then I do the next print, the printer prints nonsense text and blank pages.

So I run $ sudo service cups restart

And then printer status turn back to "Idle". And then print, and then "Sending data to printer" again.

It's not a good solution that restarting CUPS before printing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that for some printer models, Ricoh included, the generic drivers often work better than some specific vendor provided "drivers/PPD".

Also some Ricoh models need an add-on to deal well with Postscript, which seems to be the case of the Ricoh MP C2011. I would get in contact with Ricoh . Be prepared it is a paid "upgrade".

I have used the generic Postscript printer driver when creating the printer  in CUPS. I have successfully used it over the years, with Mac desktops and Linux servers/workstations. However, in your case it is paid "upgrade".

It is fairly well documented Macs only are able to print well after paying the postscript "upgrade"/card, and they also use CUPS.

Comment: How to use postscript printing? I need to convert `.pdf` file to `.ps` and then use `lp` command to print the `.ps` file, is that correct?

Comment: Hmmm,  it is a paid expansion. It is fairly well documented Macs only work well after paying the postscript expansion/card, and they also use CUPS....